# Include an association with Active Model Serializer

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In a Rails 5 application, I'm using Active Model Serializer `0.10.0.rc4`. I want to include a relation in a json hash.

I have this serializer :

```
class GroupSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :name, :subscription_ids, :nb_places, :description,
    :schedule, :course_id
end
```

And I'm using it like this :

```
resource = Group.all
ActiveModel::Serializer.serializer_for(resource).new(resource, include: :subscriptions).as_json
```

And I have this :

```
{"group"=>{:id=>1, :name=>"12", :subscription_ids=>[1, 2, 3], :nb_places=>12, :description=>nil, :schedule=>"12", :course_id=>1}}
```

I don't understand why subscriptions are not included. I don't want to use `has_many` in the serializer because it cause infinite loop when the there is multiple rules.

I want something like this :

```
{"group"=>{:id=>1, :name=>"12", :subscription_ids=>[1], :nb_places=>12, :description=>nil, :schedule=>"12", :course_id=>1, :subscriptions=>[{:id=>1,:name=>'something'}]}
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a subscriptions method like this:

```
attributes :subscriptions

def subscriptions
  object.subscriptions.as_json(only: [:id, :name])
end
```

Comment: Sorry but I wast not clear. I have subscription_ids but I don't have subscriptions data. I update the question.

Comment: I think it will be correct. It will work with `object.subscriptions.pluck([:id, :name])`. I would prefer to use something like `includes` like with the `as_json` method but I will use your solution if there is not better way. Thanks.

Comment: @Dougui ah yes, you can use `as_json` - I've updated my answer.